# Add a new animation class to the previous class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a code using JavaScript that the user can display the desired text by clicking on the icon and hide the text by clicking again.

The text is displayed with a nice animation, but when the text is being hidden, the second animation doesn't play.

Is there a way to hide the text along with the animation?

**In summary:**

I want the `.animation_out` class to be added to the `.box_excerpt` class to run a second animation when the text is being hidden.

Total codes:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.box_icon').forEach(eye => {
    eye.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let excerpt = this.parentNode.querySelector(".box_excerpt");
    if (this.classList.contains("bi-play-circle-fill")) {
        this.classList = "bi bi-power box_icon";
        excerpt.style.display = "block";
        
      $(this).closest('.box_excerpt').toggleClass('animation_out');
        
    } else {
        this.classList = "bi bi-play-circle-fill box_icon";
        excerpt.style.display = "none"
        
        $(this).closest('.box_excerpt').toggleClass('animation_out');
        
      }
  });
});
```

```css
   .box_main {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .box_mini {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 400px;
        height: 500px;
        background: #c992e8;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .box_icon {
        font-size: 80px;
        color: #4b80c4;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5%;
        left: 38%;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .box_excerpt {
        position: absolute;
        top: -25px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: -40px;
        z-index: 2;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 36px;
        padding: 117px 25px 10px;
        color: #01831b;
        text-align: justify;
        background: #9effcd;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: none;
        animation: scale-in-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
        -webkit-animation: scale-in-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes scale-in-center {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
            opacity: 1;
        }

        100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @keyframes scale-in-center {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
            opacity: 1;
        }

        100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    .animation_out {
        animation: scale-out-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
        -webkit-animation: scale-out-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes scale-out-center {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
            opacity: 1;
        }

        100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @keyframes scale-out-center {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
            opacity: 1;
        }

        100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="box_main">

        <div class="box_mini">
            <i class="bi bi-play-circle-fill  box_icon"></i>
            <p class="box_excerpt">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus nam alias velit nihil dolorum
                corporis hic quibusdam exercitationem reiciendis nostrum. Dolor nam aliquam veritatis modi sequi
                mollitia quam quod, distinctio quidem, nisi soluta natus praesentium odio assumenda sunt tempora a culpa
                pariatur labore ea quaerat porro quae dolore! Modi rerum accusantium accusamus ipsam eos sequi at ullam,
                laboriosam nemo quis omnis odit dicta voluptatem officiis? Vitae optio quos nihil molestias dicta at
                praesentium error incidunt ratione qui. Accusantium beatae ex eaque saepe cupiditate hic tenetur. Totam
                earum consequuntur atque sunt tempore possimus saepe odit. Nam, voluptatum. Quo esse possimus ipsa.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="box_mini">
            <i class="bi bi-play-circle-fill  box_icon"></i>
            <p class="box_excerpt">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus nam alias velit nihil dolorum
                corporis hic quibusdam exercitationem reiciendis nostrum. Dolor nam aliquam veritatis modi sequi
                mollitia quam quod, distinctio quidem, nisi soluta natus praesentium odio assumenda sunt tempora a culpa
                pariatur labore ea quaerat porro quae dolore! Modi rerum accusantium accusamus ipsam eos sequi at ullam,
                laboriosam nemo quis omnis odit dicta voluptatem officiis? Vitae optio quos nihil molestias dicta at
                praesentium error incidunt ratione qui. Accusantium beatae ex eaque saepe cupiditate hic tenetur. Totam
                earum consequuntur atque sunt tempore possimus saepe odit. Nam, voluptatum. Quo esse possimus ipsa.
            </p>
        </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: You can make the <P> wrap with other div and apply the css on it (or) simply add color: #9effcd; to .box_excerpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use `$(this).closest('.box_excerpt')` as box_excerpt element is not a parent of box_icon an idea can be to use `$(this).parent().find('.box_excerpt')`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.box_icon').forEach(eye => {
  eye.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let excerpt = this.parentNode.querySelector(".box_excerpt");
    if (this.classList.contains("bi-play-circle-fill")) {
      this.classList = "bi bi-power box_icon";
      excerpt.style.display = "block";
      if ($(this).data( 'notFirst')) {
        $(this).parent().find('.box_excerpt').toggleClass('animation_out');
      } else {
        !$(this).data( 'notFirst', true);
      }

    } else {
      this.classList = "bi bi-play-circle-fill box_icon";
      $(this).parent().find('.box_excerpt').toggleClass('animation_out')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box_main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box_mini {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #c992e8;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.box_icon {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #4b80c4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 38%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box_excerpt {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -40px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 117px 25px 10px;
  color: #01831b;
  text-align: justify;
  background: #9effcd;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  animation: scale-in-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  -webkit-animation: scale-in-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-in-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-in-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animation_out {
  animation: scale-out-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
  -webkit-animation: scale-out-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-out-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-out-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="box_main">

  <div class="box_mini">
    <i class="bi bi-play-circle-fill  box_icon"></i>
    <p class="box_excerpt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus nam alias velit nihil dolorum corporis hic quibusdam exercitationem reiciendis nostrum. Dolor nam aliquam veritatis modi sequi mollitia quam quod, distinctio quidem, nisi soluta natus
      praesentium odio assumenda sunt tempora a culpa pariatur labore ea quaerat porro quae dolore! Modi rerum accusantium accusamus ipsam eos sequi at ullam, laboriosam nemo quis omnis odit dicta voluptatem officiis? Vitae optio quos nihil molestias
      dicta at praesentium error incidunt ratione qui. Accusantium beatae ex eaque saepe cupiditate hic tenetur. Totam earum consequuntur atque sunt tempore possimus saepe odit. Nam, voluptatum. Quo esse possimus ipsa.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box_mini">
    <i class="bi bi-play-circle-fill  box_icon"></i>
    <p class="box_excerpt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus nam alias velit nihil dolorum corporis hic quibusdam exercitationem reiciendis nostrum. Dolor nam aliquam veritatis modi sequi mollitia quam quod, distinctio quidem, nisi soluta natus
      praesentium odio assumenda sunt tempora a culpa pariatur labore ea quaerat porro quae dolore! Modi rerum accusantium accusamus ipsam eos sequi at ullam, laboriosam nemo quis omnis odit dicta voluptatem officiis? Vitae optio quos nihil molestias
      dicta at praesentium error incidunt ratione qui. Accusantium beatae ex eaque saepe cupiditate hic tenetur. Totam earum consequuntur atque sunt tempore possimus saepe odit. Nam, voluptatum. Quo esse possimus ipsa.
    </p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Hello. Your answer is correct for running on one box, but your code has the opposite effect on the next box.

Comment: When I click on the first box the code works, but when I click on the second box the text closes instead of opening!!!

Comment: we not haeve to toggle the animation class first time. it was the boolean that check if it have already played. I edit my reply to use dataset on icon to check if it can play animation or not

Answer (score -1):

You can make the 'p' tag wrap with other div and apply the css on it (or) simply add color: #9effcd; to .box_excerpt

Like,

```
.box_excerpt {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -40px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 117px 25px 10px;
    color: #01831b;
    text-align: justify;
    background: #9effcd;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    animation: scale-in-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    -webkit-animation: scale-in-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    color: #9effcd;
}
```